# Sudo permissions by ldap groups via nslcd

Tags: permissions, sudo, ldap, active-directory

I have a problem with my sudo permissions in an MS ActiveDirectory to Debian LDAP authentication/authorization setup.

**What I have so far**
I've configured nslcd with libpam-ldap via ldaps and ssh login is working great.

```
getent passwd myuser
myuser:*:10001:10015:myuser:/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```

On my ActiveDirectory Server, the Unix Package is installed which adds the necessary attributes like posixGroup, posixAccount, gid, gidNumber, uid, uidNumber and so on.

My example user looks like this: 
(I choose 10000+ to be on the safe side)

```
cn: myuser
uid: myuser
uidNumber: 10015
gidNumber: 10000
```

I can restrict SSH logins by adding the following to /etc/nslcd.conf

```
filter passwd (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(|(memberOf=CN=group1,OU=groups,DC=domain,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=group2,OU=groups,DC=domain,DC=com)))
```

This specifies that only users with objecClass=posixAccount and group either group1 or group2 can login.

So far so good. However, I can't tell sudo to use those groups.

**Here is what I tried**
in /etc/sudoers

```
// This one works, but only because the user has gidNumber=10000 set. 
// It doesn't matter if a group with this ID actually exist or not. 
// So it's not really permission by LDAP group.
%#10000 ALL=(root) ALL


// This is what I want, but it doesn't work.
%group1 ALL=(root) ALL
```

**The Problem**
Somehow I need to tell sudo to take the requesting username, check what ldap-groups it belongs to and then see if the permissions for that group are sufficient to execute the command or not.

Unfortuntely I have no idea where to start. Everything else works so far and I'm only stuck with sudo permissions. I thought about mapping the users gidNumber field to the groups gidNumber field but I don't know if mapping a user field to a group field is even possible.

I don't think so, since mapping in nslcd is specified like this

```
map passwd field1 field2
```

and passwd tells nslcd that it has to mapp user fields. Instead of passwd I could use groups, but not both of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry about the long post, but it seems to work. I just had a typo in sudoers file. Took me a bit long to find it though, since the syntax was still correct but I couldn't execute any commands.

However, it's working now.

```
 // Problem was that one ALL was missing, allowing me to execute no root cmds.
 %group1 ALL=(root) !/bin/su

 // Fixed it
 %group1 ALL=(root) ALL, !/bin/su
```

Update: I realized a bit late but I also changed the following in /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
sudoers:        ldap files
```

I just didn't think it was the fix because I still had the above mentioned sudoers typo.

Problem solved :)

Comment: Incidentally, why do you negate /bin/su? If you want to prevent a user from getting a root shell, then your !/bin/su is insufficient. sudo bash or cp /bin/su /tmp/su && sudo /tmp/su are just two of many ways to still get a root shell on most systems. (ignoring grsec, systrace policies, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, also !/usr/sbin/visudo is missing. it was essentially just a test to see if a command is really blocked.

Comment: @etherfish your correct on that but one really should be mounting tmp, var, /dev/shm, /home and the like as noexec thus leaving only /{,usr,usr/local}/[s]bin as the only spots that are mounted with exec perms.

Answer (score 2):

I went with [assigning local groups to users](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication#Assign_local_groups_to_users) through pam_group to get the same functionality. In `/etc/security/groups.conf` I added the following line

```
*;*;%administrators;Al0000-2400;adm,sudo,lpadmin
```

So any LDAP user that belongs to the LDAP group `administrators` gets mapped to the local `adm`, `sudo`, and `lpadmin` groups on the box. Seems simpler than having to install `sudo-ldap`, unless I am missing something?

Comment: I like the idea, but it didn't work for me, can you improve your answer? Full answers should link to another page